# IIS manager crash on adding ftp site

Tags: ftp, iis-8.5, server-crashes

This is the first time i want to run ftp on this server, Just added the WebServer then FTP role and IIS manager will crash on adding a ftp site, Adding Website works fine and there is a Website already.

Found [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1208078.aspx) on iis forum: (which i actually don't know what should i do)

> Based on the call stack, when you created this site you specified an invalid binding and led to the crash.

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard x64
- IIS v8.5
- Ram 2gb / Cpu xeon 2.6ghz
- DotNetFramework 2, 3.5, 4, 4.7 installed

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xumGf.png)

What is the cause ? What can i do about it ? Can i do it manually without iis manager like with cmd, powershell ?

Found this issue on the internet but there wasn't any straight answer on this.